# can't check if pkill command is successful or not

Tags: bash

I have this kind of code in my bash

```
pkill <stuff>
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

But it always goes into the fail part.
How can I check if the pkill command is successful?

Comment: Hint: lookup `man pkill` under `EXIT STATUS` section

Comment: Are you sure that you enter the fail branch even if pkill is successful? Looks like your pkill command fails all the time and the `if` does exactly what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4):

As written in the manpage, pkill have different exit status code:

```
EXIT STATUS
   0      One or more processes matched the criteria.
   1      No processes matched.
   2      Syntax error in the command line.
   3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
```

Your code does analyse the exit code (Thats whats the $? is standing for) but you do not check if you have 1, 2 or 3... you should (!!!) check for this also:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pkill <stuff>
pkillexitstatus=$?

if [ $pkillexitstatus -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "one or more processes matched the criteria"
elif [ $pkillexitstatus -eq 1]; then
    echo "no processes matched"
elif [ $pkillexitstatus -eq 2]; then
    echo "syntax error in the command line"
elif [ $pkillexitstatus -eq 3]; then
    echo "fatal error"
else
    echo UNEXPECTED
fi
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. All exit codes different from 0 are errors so OPs script seems fine.

Comment: Exit Status 1 is not neccessary an error.

Due @Lanodisoft did not give any further information, no one can help him, except himself :-)

My answer should help him, to better understand how pkill communicates with its caller/his bash script, so that he can figure out why it is not working as he expects it.